# What's a faster way of decoding a string from a dictionary? (Python)

Tags: python, string, decoding

I have to decode a string of 1's and 0's using a dictionary of characters with corresponding binary codes. The dictionary is set up like this:

```
self.codes = {'a': '00', 'h': '111', 'e': '110', 'l': '01', 'o': '10'}
```

The codes are such that no binary code is the prefix of any other. At the moment I have this function to do the decoding:

```
def decode(self, ciphertext):
        start = 0
        while start < len(ciphertext):
            for k in self.codes:
                res = ciphertext.find(self.codes[k], start)
                if res == start:
                    decoded += k
                    start += len(self.codes[k])
        return decoded
```

(Where ciphertext = the text to be decoded, and self.codes = the dictionary representing the coding system)

Unsurprisingly, this is really slow. Can anyone point me towards a more efficient algorithm for this kind of thing?

[edit] Thanks all for the great suggestions. I'll try implementing them in a couple of hours when I get home.

Comment: if you flip `codes` around so the binary codes are the keys and the decoded values are the values, then can't you do very efficient hash access?

Comment: I think because the binary codes are of different length decoding is much more complex,  You can't just split every 2 or 3 chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
    self.codes = {'a': '00', 'h': '111', 'e': '110', 'l': '01', 'o': '10'}
    self.decode_codes = {value: key for key, value in self.codes.items()}

def decode(self, ciphertext):
    result = ''
    chunk = ''

    for c in ciphertext:
        chunk += c

        if chunk in self.decode_codes:
            result += self.decode_codes[chunk]
            chunk = ''


    return result
```

Since you said that no two codes are contained within the beginning of one another, this approach will work.

Comment: I changed your for loop slightly and got this to work: `for c in ciphertext:
        chunk += c
        if chunk in decode_codes:
            result += decode_codes[chunk]
            chunk = ''`

Answer (score 1):

Your code will run a lot faster if you flip keys and values:

```
self.codes = {'00': 'a', '111': 'h', '110': 'e', '01': 'l', '10': 'o'}
```

Now you can do pseudocode like this:

ciphertext = your ciphertext (e.g. "001111100110")

plaintext = ""

currenttoken = ""

1) add the current bit of ciphertext onto the end of currenttoken

2) Does self.codes contain currenttoken?

2a) If so, add self.codes[currenttoken] to plaintext, and currenttoken = ""

Dictionary access is O(1), O(1) over the length of a string is O(n).

If you also need the unflipped keys/values to make ciphering the string very fast, then I suggest you have two dictionaries, one for encoding fast one for decoding fast.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more efficient decoder that uses a reverse dictionary. I've tried to calculate as much stuff up front as possible.

```
codes = {'a': '00', 'h': '111', 'e': '110', 'l': '01', 'o': '10'}

# generate the reverse dictionary and min/max length from the above
decodes = dict((v, k) for (k, v) in codes.iteritems())
# can use dict comprehension for above in Python >= 2.7
lenrange = range(min(len(k) for k in decodes), max(len(k) for k in decodes) + 1)
# for Python 3, add here: lenrange = list(lenrange)    

def decode(ciphertext):
    start, plaintext = 0, []
    plaintext_append = plaintext.append  # for speed
    while True:
        for n in lenrange:
            key = ciphertext[start:start+n]
            if key in decodes:
                plaintext_append(decodes[key])
                start += n
                break
        else:     # return result when code can't be found (usually at end)
            return "".join(plaintext)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement Blender's answer and had to make a few tiny changes:

```
codes = {'a': '00', 'h': '111', 'e': '110', 'l': '01', 'o': '10'}
decode_codes = {value: key for key, value in codes.items()}

def decode(ciphertext):
    result = ''
    chunk = ''

    for c in ciphertext:
        chunk += c
        if chunk in decode_codes:
            result += decode_codes[chunk]
            chunk = ''

    return result

def encode(plaintext):
    return ''.join(codes[c] for c in plaintext)

print decode(encode("hello"))
```